# Java Date year calculation is off by year for two days

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

This caused a Y2K-style bug in my software if you can imagine.  Strange thing is the off-by-one year calculation only occurs for two days in the year, which I'm less sure how to troubleshoot.

The output:

```
03-Jan-2013
02-Jan-2013
01-Jan-2013
31-Dec-2013 ** strange
30-Dec-2013 ** strange
29-Dec-2012
28-Dec-2012
27-Dec-2012
26-Dec-2012
25-Dec-2012
```

I am not sure which part of the Java date utilities could cause such an error.

The code (since the test is so small I included a complete working program):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateT {

        private static String getFormattedBackscanStartTime(int days) {

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY");
                Calendar workingDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                workingDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1 * days);

                String formattedStartTime = dateFormat.format(workingDate.getTime());
                return formattedStartTime;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {

                for(int i = 35; i < 45; i++) {
                        System.out.println(getFormattedBackscanStartTime(i));
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you would benefit from this. https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2096000

Comment: Be aware that the `Calendar` & `SimpleDateFormat` classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). Supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. A modern approach uses the `LocalDate`, `ZoneId`, and `DateTimeFormatter` classes instead.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
"dd-MMM-YYYY"
```

`YYYY` is the week-year, not the calendar year. You want `yyyy` instead.

The last two days of calendar year 2012 were in the first week of week-year 2013. You should normally only use the week year in conjunction with the "week of year" specifier (`w`).

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming you are using Java 1.7.

The code snippet above will not work with Java 1.6 as `SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YYYY")` will raise an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` (YYYY is not available in Java 1.6)

You need to use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY`.

```
Y -> week-year
y -> year
```

[here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

It works great with `yyyy`:

```
$ java DateT
03-Jan-2013
02-Jan-2013
01-Jan-2013
31-Dec-2012
30-Dec-2012
29-Dec-2012
28-Dec-2012
27-Dec-2012
26-Dec-2012
25-Dec-2012
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in your date format string - year should be `yyyy` not `YYYY`.

If you print the value of `workingDate.getTime()` in each iteration of the loop, you'll see it has the expected values:

```
Thu Jan 03 11:19:33 EST 2013
Wed Jan 02 11:19:33 EST 2013
Tue Jan 01 11:19:33 EST 2013
Mon Dec 31 11:19:33 EST 2012
Sun Dec 30 11:19:33 EST 2012
Sat Dec 29 11:19:33 EST 2012
Fri Dec 28 11:19:33 EST 2012
Thu Dec 27 11:19:33 EST 2012
Wed Dec 26 11:19:33 EST 2012
Tue Dec 25 11:19:33 EST 2012
```

Therefore the problem lies in the SimpleDateFormat usage.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, here’s the modern answer using `LocalDate` (as recommended by Basil Bourque in a comment).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DateT {

    private static DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", Locale.US);

    private static String getFormattedBackscanStartTime(int days) {
        return LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).minusDays(days).format(dateFormatter);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(int i = 155; i < 165; i++) {
            System.out.println(getFormattedBackscanStartTime(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Running this today I got

```
04-Jan-2017
03-Jan-2017
02-Jan-2017
01-Jan-2017
31-Dec-2016
30-Dec-2016
29-Dec-2016
28-Dec-2016
27-Dec-2016
26-Dec-2016
```

A few things to note:

- Give an explicit locale to your formatter to control the langauge of your output. Even if you just pass `Locale.getDefault()` you are telling the reader that you have thought about locale and made a decision.
- Similarly give an explicit time zone to `LocalDate.now()` to tell the reader you’ve made a decision (for example `ZoneId.of("America/New_York")` for a specific time zone; `ZoneId.systemDefault()` for the JVM’s current time zone setting).
- I find the code simpler and more straightforward than the code using the oldfashioned `Calendar` class. This is typical for the newer classes.
- I have used `uuuu` for year. `yyyy` (lowercase) works too, there will only be a difference for years before the common era (AKA BC).

Comment: Could you please separate the `LocalDate.now` line into separate commands so you can see what classes you are working with?

Comment: And... here is a way to convert from `java.util.Date`: https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-to-localdate-and-localdatetime Not sure if this makes sense if you are using libraries that rely on old Date.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use lower case y for the year. Try this:

```
   SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```