# year change with simpledateformat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I get informations on entity via jpa . 
the date  31/12/2018 dd/MM/YYYY became 31/12/2019.
I must be  wrong on a simpledateformat option.

```
LOG.info("date de création :" +entite.getCreatedt ());
SimpleDateFormat sdf =new SimpleDateFormat ( "dd/MM/YYYY" );
LOG.info("date de création formatée :" + sdf.format(entite.getCreatedt ()));
```

the createdt field from my entity is defined as above :

```
@Column(name = "CREATEDT")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date createdt;
```

I get the result :
Infos:   date de création :Mon Dec 31 00:00:00 CET 2018
Infos:   date de création formatée :31/12/2019

can you explain why the 2018 became 2019
I tried with

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ( "dd/MM/YYYY", new Locale("fr", "FR") );
```

but the result was the same

thanks

Comment: "Y" is the wrong letter for the year, use lower case "y" (upper case means "week-based-year")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between year-of-era and week-based-year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431882/difference-between-year-of-era-and-week-based-year) (refers to [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), but is also valid for [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html))

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755742/java-date-year-calculation-is-off-by-year-for-two-days

Comment: Why are you still using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, those troublesome and long outdated classes? A modern JPA implementation should handle `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for you. Then use a `DateTimeFormatter` for formatting it.